# ModuleNotFoundError after installing dependency

Tags: python, pytest, python-venv

I'm hoping to contribute to [this Python library](https://github.com/simonw/llm) and am following [the contribution instructions](https://llm.datasette.io/en/stable/contributing.html).

I've followed the instructions to check out the code and make a virtual environment using `venv`. Then I installed the dependencies, which seems to run fine:

```
(venv) % pip install -e '.[test]'
 ...
Building wheels for collected packages: llm
  Building editable for llm (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for llm: filename=llm-0.10-0.editable-py3-none-any.whl size=8542 sha256=991975d8a5f002bd8a3325ee47ef673513538241229ab670fbb267bac187f143
  Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/h5/r_p1fbvx13g1hf0c15pjx60h0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-tmra42no/wheels/cb/85/32/0bf57228d9eab277b05cd64c34a0e608ae4cbaebc42529b8ce
Successfully built llm
Installing collected packages: llm
  Attempting uninstall: llm
    Found existing installation: llm 0.10
    Uninstalling llm-0.10:
      Successfully uninstalled llm-0.10
Successfully installed llm-0.10
```

I'm trying to install the `llm` library to work on the code, following [these instructions](https://llm.datasette.io/en/stable/contributing.html).

Now I try to run `pytest`, but I get this error:

```
(venv) % pytest                  
ImportError while loading conftest '/Users/me/llm/tests/conftest.py'.
tests/conftest.py:3: in <module>
    import llm
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llm'
```

This is weird since in the previous step, the `llm` library seemed to have installed OK.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Checking python paths and installed packages:

```
(venv) % which python3
/Users/me/llm/venv/bin/python3
(venv) % python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
[...'/Users/me/llm/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages']
(venv) % ls /Users/me/llm/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages
... llm-0.10.dist-info
```

If Python3 has the virtual environment's `site-packages` directory in its path, and llm is in there, why can't the test script see llm?

Comment: Does `pytest` point to the same interpreter installation? Is `pytest` installed in the venv? Check e.g. via `pip show pytest`. If it is installed, check whether `python -m pytest` exhibits the same error. My suspicion is that you have `pytest` installed outside of the venv and the `pytest` executable of this "outside" installation is in shell path.